# How to use list view and day view in Tapku calendar?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, tapku

I am new to iPhone development.Now i am working on calendar application.I used TapkuLibrary for my calendar application.By this library i can use only the month view.How to implement day view and list view? Please help me..

Comment: Tapku allows Monthview only.For DayView i use another [library](https://github.com/muhku/calendar-ui).From this library i took some classes and then implement into Tapku library..

Answer (score -1):

Tapku now has a `TKCalendarDayView`, check the latest at  http://github.com/devinross/tapkulibrary